# Python reload error

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm using Python in IDLE, and I have a line `reload(sim_map_training)`. However, when I  run the file, it says `NameError: name 'sim_map_training' is not defined`, even though I'm sure I have a file `sim_map_training.py` in the same directory as the file. I'm really confused.. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `sim_map_training` in the context where you're reloading must refer to the module. Just writing

```
import sim_map_training  # =  sim_map_training = sys.modules['sim_map_training']
reload(sim_map_training)
```

will do.